# Adding to .txt file in PHP instead of overwriting it

Tags: php

I have this line of PHP code here

```
<?php
file_put_contents('query.txt', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY));
?>
```

Whenever

```
phpfile.php?blablabla
```

is queried it writes a query.txt with the parameter in it, in this case, blablabla.

BUT, when I do this, it deletes the past query.txt file and writes a totally new one.

I want the queries to be ADDED into the .txt file. So there can be as many queries and possible and every single value entered will be lined up in the .txt file..

For example

I want it so phpfile.php?test is visited, query.txt looks like this

```
test
```

after that, phpfile.php?test2 is visited

now query.txt looks like this

```
test
test2
```

and this goes on forever.

How do I do this?

p.s.: sorry, I'm totally a Java type. I'm an absolute beginner to PHP.

Comment: There's the `FILE_APPEND` flag. See http://php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: possible duplicate of [file\_put\_contents, file\_append and line breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536564/file-put-contents-file-append-and-line-breaks)

Comment: Are you aware that most web servers have a configurable log file in which you could see all the query strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to append to the file, so you should use something along the lines of

```
$handle =  fopen("myfile.txt", "a");
fwrite ($handle, parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY));
fclose($handle);
```

You can find all the other read/write file open flags at the docs.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

It appears you can also just pass a flag with your existing code, as that will abstract the file handle open/close from you;

```
file_put_contents('query.txt', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Just `a` is needed, he doesn't need to read. But +1

Comment: He will probably want to append a newline character as well.

Answer (score 3):

Add `FILE_APPEND` as 3rd argument to `file_put_contents()`. Example (`.PHP_EOL` to add new line):

```
$data = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY).PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('query.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```