# Write in a .txt File from a form in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998961/php-write-file-from-input-to-txt) and I wanted to ask a question in the comment but didn't have enough reputation. So I'm asking the question here.

I have a form in HTML:

```
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
Name : <input name="field1" type="text" />
Email : <input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
```

And a processing script in php, `myprocessingscript.php` :

```
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
  $data = 'comments.txt' . $_POST['field1'] . ' ' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
  $ret = file_put_contents('comments.txt', $data);

  if ($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error Sending The Comment');
  } 

  else {
    echo "The Comment Has Been Sent Succesfully !";
  }
} 

else {
  die('Fill in The Form Please !');
}

if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
  $data = 'comments.txt' . $_POST['field1'] . ' ' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
  $ret = file_put_contents('comments.txt', $data);

  if ($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error Sending The Comment');
  } 

  else {
    echo "The Comment Has Been Sent Succesfully !";
  }
} 

else {
  die('no post data to process');
}
```

When I write something in the form to a text file (comments.txt) the previous text is deleted - what should I do?

Comment: What is your question?  And, you aren't supposed to ask questions in comments, you are supposed to ask new questions as you have done.

Comment: ... the funny thing is - you've not actually asked a question?!

Comment: @Brad I Pressed Enter As a Mistake ! I Edited it Afer 20 seconds !

Comment: unable to understand question ..its looks funny..

Comment: What's with capitalising every word?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3536594/362536

Comment: @superphonic Consider for a moment that not everyone on the planet is a native English speaker.

Comment: @Brad I refuse to believe there is any language out there that arbitrarily capitalises every word within a sentence. Obviously referring to those languages based on the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @superphonic What would that have to do with anything?  This person is clearly trying English, and is obviously not familiar with all of the rules.

Comment: I've reformatted the question into proper Englanderish like, so you can stop arguing now :P

Comment: Sorry Bros ! if you Downvoted this question because of that i didn't ask my question at first , please remove your vote !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add the 'append' flag to `file_put_contents()` :

```
file_put_contents('comments.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

See : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: May wanna add `lock_ex` there, to prevent.. lots of bad stuff :)

Comment: @SamFisher What Does it Do ?!

Comment: LOCK_EX - Exclusive lock (writer). Prevent other processes from accessing the file

Prevents changes being done to the file while the changes are beind done to the file :) To add it to the upper stuff, you do:

`file_put_contents('comments.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`